# How to find and unwrap elements from their parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So simply, I am trying to find and unwrap elements on my page. There is a slight problem going wrong with my WYSIWYG editor, and I need to apply a fix.

For example:

**This is how my HTML currently looks like**

```
<h1>
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <img src="images/img.jpg" />
</h1>
<h1>
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <p>Some text here</p>
</h1>
```

**This how how my HTML should look like**

```
<p>Some text here</p>
<p>Some text here</p>
<p>Some text here</p>
<img src="images/img.jpg" />
<p>Some text here</p>
<p>Some text here</p>
```

How can I completely remove the `h1` tag?

This is my attempt. I am running this once the entire page has been loaded.

```
if ($('h1').find('p').length) {
    $('p', this).unwrap();
}
```

PS. This always occurs at random, there is no pattern. Can sometimes happen to many elements, and sometimes only to a few.

Comment: Why do you use `p` tag inside `<h1>`?

Comment: As I stated, it is my WYSIWYG editor messing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can select the children of `h1` and unwrap them like

```
$('h1 > *').unwrap();
```

---

```
var $h1 = $('h1');
$h1.contents().unwrap();
$h1.remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LPuB2/)

Note: the value referred by `this` will not change inside the `if` condition - from the way use have used it I assume you are thinking `this` inside the `if` block is referring to the `h1` element

---

Comment: The first method you suggested seems to completely remove the `h1` from the page, which is great. So why are you suggesting that it doesnt?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**:

```
$('h1').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).find('*'); });
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KDjw3/)**